# My function works when in the console, but not from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, express

I'm pretty new to jQuery, and I have the following function:

```js
$('#new-game').click( evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    console.log("HELP ME");
    alert('button');
    startGame();
});
```

This function works when I copy it into the Google inspector console, but nothing happens when I  click the button without first adding the function to the console.

```html
<!-- jQuery ---------------------------------->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- JS ----------------------------->
    <script src="/js/grammarian.js"></script>
```

As you can see, my js file is after my jQuery, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Most likely you're executing the code before the body and all its elements exist.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Your jQuery and UI versions are ancient. You should investigate whether you can upgrade. It's usually fairly painless (directly converting `live()` to `on()` is 95% of the battle).

Comment: also in modern JS (well, "modern"... every browser since 2012) you load scripts that modify the DOM using the `defer` attribute, so `<script src="..." defer></script>`. This will load your script as usual but won't _run_ it until the DOM is ready for polling/manipulating.